# Not able to pass a dynamic range as argument

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba, scripting

When I tried to use the function below, I was unable to pass a dynamic range as an argument

```
Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Excel.Range) As String
    Dim finalValue As String

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
        finalValue = finalValue + CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell

    ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
End Function

Sub MyMacro()
    MsgBox ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange([A1:C3])
End Sub
```

I could not use

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim rng as range
    Rng=Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row))
    MsgBox ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange([Rng])
End Sub
```

Comment: Add "Set" keyword before "Rng", so that it reads "Set Rng=Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row))"

Comment: Why could you not use that? Did it generate a compilation error? I don't see where you've provided that information.

Comment: Either this is VB.NET or it's VBA.  Why do you have both tags?  Which is it?

Comment: And what happens when you try to pass the Range as an argument? Do you get an error message? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

It's your syntax which is wrong.

To define an object you need to use the `Set` keyword; the `.Row` function returns a `Long` not a `Range` object so you need to remove that; and you simply pass the `rng` variable in your function.

```
Function ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(sourceRange As Range) As String
    Dim finalValue As String

    Dim cell As Excel.Range

    For Each cell In sourceRange.Cells
        finalValue = finalValue &  CStr(cell.Value)
    Next cell

    ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange = finalValue
End Function

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    MsgBox ConcatinateAllCellValuesInRange(rng)
End Sub
```